# Added mistakenly library file in project,cause all project to error in android stdio

Tags: android

i have done some mistake in my code ,try to add external library but it gives me error in my code,i have deleted library but stills it gernerates all my code error

Android Dex: [CardandWirelessPanama] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/croem/web/top_up/RechargeSummaryActivity$13;
Android Dex: [CardandWirelessPanama] at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
Android Dex: [CardandWirelessPanama] at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
Android Dex: [CardandWirelessPanama] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:459)
Android Dex: [CardandWirelessPanama] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
Android Dex: [CardandWirelessPanama] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:398)
Android Dex: [CardandWirelessPanama] at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:135)
Android Dex: [CardandWirelessPanama] at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)

Answer (score 0):

after delete all that library clear application 
and rebuild it hope it will resolve